Holomorphic mappings of Riemann Sphere that preserves each hemisphere
What are some examples of holomorphic functions that satisfy the title?
Especially for Mobius Transformation $f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$
Is there a requirement on $ad-bc>0$ ?

A special easy Moebius transformation mapping the unit circle to itself is
$$w=\frac{z-z_0}{\overline{z_0} z +1 }$$
It can be combined with rigid rotations $z=e^{i \alpha }\ z', w=w'\ e^{i\beta}$
Setting $z\to e^{i \phi}$ yields
$$ w \ \overline w =\frac{\left(e^{i \phi }-(a+i \ b)\right) \quad\left(e^{-i \phi }-(a-i\ b)\right)}{\left(e^{i \phi } (-a+i\ b)+1\right)\quad  \left(e^{-i \phi } (-a-i \ b)+1\right)}=\frac{1+a^2+b^2-2 a \ \cos (\phi )+2 i\  b \sin (\phi )}{1+a^2+b^2-2 a \ \cos (\phi )+2 i\  b \sin (\phi )} =1$$
The trigonometry is so triggy, that its not easy to derive the form by (C) algebra (S)
Set $z_0=a+i b$ inside the unit circle.
